# How can I add a scope to a connected app for a given user?

Tags: api, oauth2

I am new to Salesforce. I am admin of the Salesforce at my company. We've hired an outside company to do some integration with us, via Oauth and a connected app. They tell me that they need the "api" scope for this connected app.

Right now, if I do a test `curl` call, I get back:

```
"scope":"openid id content"
```

I don't know where these 3 scopes come from. I did not explicitly assign them.

But I also need an "api" scope I think. How do I make that appear?

But how can I grant that? I ran some searches and found this:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5

which lists all of the scopes, but doesn't explain how to grant these scopes to a particular connected app. Or do I grant the scope to a particular user?

I logged into the connected app and I see a place where I can add "custom Oauth scopes" but I don't think I need a custom scope, I think I just need the standard "api" scope. But how can I add it so this outside company can use it?

If I:

click on Setup

search for Connected Apps

click on "Manage Connected Apps"

find my connected app in the list

click "edit" next to my connected app

I see the following, but I don't see anything about scopes.

[image]

I do see this list of permissions, but I cannot find any way to edit these:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the connected App in edit mode under "API (Enable OAuth Settings)" you can add the scopes for the connected app and your [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5) describes what entitlement user received with each scope [image]

If you want to add "API" scope you. should add "Manage user data via APIs (api)" as selected OAuth scope[image]

Comment: I cannot find the screen that you are talking about. I go into Setup, look for "Connected Apps" then click "Manage Connected Apps" then click "edit" next to my connected app, but I don't see anything like what you've posted.

Comment: Hope you find your answer, my bad editing a connected app is little confusing

Comment: @JeffGallant For future users:  Editing an app through "App Manager" and "Manage Connected Apps" gives entirely different options.  The page in these screenshots is accessed through Setup > Platform Tools > Apps > App Manager.  Took me forever to figure that out.